# cakephp save related belongsTo

Tags: cakephp, save

I have hasMany relation between Employee and Schedule.
When editing an Employee, I manage to get the current schedule and populate my form.

Upon saving, I use:

```
        if ($this->Employee->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Employee->Schedule->save($this->request->data, $validate = false);
            ....
        }
```

Employee data saves fine, but Schedule record is left untouched.

I'm actually providing the id as part as the array. On my controller, debug($this->request->data) shows:

```
array(
'Employee' => array(
    'emp_position' => '1',
    'name' => 'the name',
    'emp_gender' => '1',
    'emp_father' => '',
    'emp_mother' => '',
    'emp_dob' => 'October 13, 1964',
    ...
    ..
),
'Schedule' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '7',
        'ho_lu2' => '10:00',
        'ho_ma2' => '01:00',
        'ho_mi2' => '00:00',
        'ho_ju2' => '00:00',
        'ho_vi2' => '00:00',    
        'ho_do4' => '00:00'
    )
)
)
```

.

```
***************** Update ************
```

I think it has to do with foreign keys being different on my two tables

My employees table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_appserial` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
```

(Please note that on Employee table, emp_appserial is my pk autoincr, and employee_id can be null for some records)

My Schedules table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedules` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
```

Since I've linked these tables using a different field, i use foreignKey:

On my model, I linked: 
Employee Model:

```
        var $hasMany = array(
            'Schedule' => array(
                'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',  //(field on Schedule)
                'dependent' => true
            )
        );

        public $primaryKey = 'emp_appserial'
```

Schedule Model:

```
var $belongsTo = array('Employee',
    'Employee' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'emp_appserial'    //(field on Employee)
    )
);
```

My posted data now includes employee_id for Schedule, and emp_appserial for Employee

```
array(
'Employee' => array(
    'id' => null,
    'emp_appserial' => '119'
    ...
),
'Schedule' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '6',
        'name' => 'segundo horario',
        'emp_appserial' => '119',   
        'employee_id' => '119'
    )
)
)
```

(tried appending to Schedule both id and serial to try my luck- not good.)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: How is `$this->request->data` structured? Could you print that array please? If it is structured right, you could use saveAll.

Comment: @tykenn, Thanks a lot. It worked!. Actually I tried to implement the Answer first -had not seen your comment yet- and updated my question. However this worked. Still, I'd like to know if my foreignKeys issue has negative effect on saving as     $this->Employee->Schedule->save($this->request->data...   Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As a rule, when working with hasOne, hasMany, and belongsTo associations, its all about keying" - CakePHP Manual.

Your Employee array has to pass an id and the schedule array needs to have an employee_id so cake knows what are the linked models.

Comment: thank you so much. Tried sending keys and still no luck. I think it has to do with foreign keys being different on my two tables. Will you p-p-please see updated question? Added some tables detail.

Comment: if it's not much trouble, I'd still love to know if my foreignKeys issue has negative effect on saving as $this->Employee->Schedule->save($this->request->data... Thank you so much.